# Image to expand or collapse with page size

Tags: html, css

I have a static left navigation on a page but the content of that page can change which tends to leave a decent amount of white space. I was wanting to place a image below the navigation that would show as the oage got bigger but not if the page was small enough to just show the nav with nothing below it.

The page is formatted in a table (I know but I didn't make it) so the left nav  expands with the content .

Comment: use media query. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Can you post your code here using JSFiddle ?